# Prevent JPopupMenu from being covered by task bar

Tags: java, swing, jpopupmenu

How do I make my `JPopupMenu` appear above the task bar? In other words, how do I force it to honour screen limits so it doesn't get covered? Take Android Studio's pop up menu for example:

Normal position:

[image]

And when I drag the window near the bottom task bar, the pop up "adapts" and appears above it:

[image]

And now my test case:
Normal position:
[image]

Near the task bar (you can see how, unlike the Android Studio one, part of the pop up disappears under the task bar):

[image]

Code for the test case:

**Test.java**

```
public class Test extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public Test() {
        initComponents();
    }

    public void initUI() {

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        btnMenu = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        btnMenu.setText("Click for Menu");
        btnMenu.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btnMenuActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(291, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(btnMenu)
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(266, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(btnMenu)
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void btnMenuActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
        JPopupMenu menu = new JPopupMenu();
        menu.add(new PopBody());
        menu.show(this, btnMenu.getLocation().x - 95, btnMenu.getLocation().y + 60);
    }                                       

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        }
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> new Test().setVisible(true));
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton btnMenu;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

**PopBody.java**

```
public class PopBody extends javax.swing.JPanel {

    public PopBody() {
        initComponents();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        lblBody = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        btnOK = new javax.swing.JButton();

        lblBody.setText("Panel body");

        btnOK.setText("OK");
        btnOK.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btnOKActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(this);
        this.setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(77, 77, 77)
                .addComponent(lblBody)
                .addContainerGap(92, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(btnOK)
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(73, 73, 73)
                .addComponent(lblBody)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 56, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(btnOK)
                .addContainerGap())
        );
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void btnOKActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      

    }                                     


    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton btnOK;
    private javax.swing.JLabel lblBody;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: Make the JPopupMenu [heavyweight](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/swing/JPopupMenu.html#setLightWeightPopupEnabled(boolean)).

Comment: @VGR What will that achieve?

Comment: Nearly all Swing components are lightweight by default, which means they are not native screen allocations;  instead, Swing draws them inside the window.  A heavyweight component uses a native rectangular area, so it can overlap other native elements.  The trade-off is that the heavyweight component uses more system resources, though that’s probably less of a concern than it was twenty years ago.

Comment: I just called `menu.setLightWeightPopupEnabled(false);` on the JPopup and it behaves the same way.

Answer (score 2):

I stumbled across this problem myself and came up with this solution.

```
private void btnMenuActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    JPopupMenu popup = new JPopupMenu();
    popup.add(new PopBody());
    popup.pack();

    int popUpHeight = popup.getPreferredSize().height;
    //determines the max available size of the screen
    Rectangle windowBounds = GraphicsEnvironment.
        getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getMaximumWindowBounds();
    Point invokerPosition = ((Component)evt.getSource()).getLocationOnScreen();

    if (invokerPosition.y + popUpHeight > windowBounds.height) {
        //get the negative margin and use it as the y-offset
        popup.show(this, 0, windowBounds.height - (invokerPosition.y + popUpHeight));
    }
    else {
        popup.show(this, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

I'm not sure about your hard-coded offsets though.