# Java, get Window Bounds for current screen

Tags: java, user-interface, awt

I'm using two monitors with different resolutions. This returns the display where my component is located:

```
DisplayMode dm = invoker.getGraphicsConfiguration().getDevice().getDisplayMode();
```

And this returns window bounds of the screen, with taskbar accounted for:

```
Rectangle windowBounds = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getMaximumWindowBounds();
```

The problem is that the second line of code always returns primary screen bounds but I want to get secondary screen bounds when my component is located on the second screen. Is there a way to combine these two lines to get current screen window bounds?

dm has getHeight() and getWidth() for current screen but they do not account for windows taskbar.

Comment: I've been programming Java GUIs for nigh on 2 decades & never needed the screen size. Why does your app need it? See also [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)

Comment: @AndrewThompson I have a JPopMenu which is placed with show() method. When the invoker is too close to the Windows taskbar the JPopMenu is drawn under the taskbar. I've used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55570248/13490121)  solution, to offset y position, and it worked but if you have two monitors with different resolutions the GraphicEnviroment still uses the size values from the main monitor even when JPopMenu and invoker is on the second monitor.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell, you want to get the screen size of the current device in order to personalize your applications dimensions.
You can do this with Java Toolkit class.

First get and store the screen size:

```
Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
```

Then store the width and height of the screen in integers:

```
// screen size width
int screenWidth = screenSize.getWidth;
// screen size height
int screenHeight = screenSize.getHeight;
```

After you have stored the width and height into integers, you can then use and compare them like one would with other primitive variables.